# SQL IF statement pulling separate columns

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```
SELECT IF(description NOT LIKE ('A A%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A E%'), null, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A I%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A O%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A U%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description)))
FROM film_text;
```

Hello,

To give some context, I am using the sakila sample data set. What I'm trying to do is change all the titles that have "A " to "An ". I still want to return the titles that start with "A " while changing all the other titles.

What's happening is that it is querying 5 different columns which I sort of thought would happen since I am doing 5 different IF statements.

Is there a way to correct all the titles that have the second word starting with vowels while still querying the other titles and have it show up all in one column?

Thank you!

Comment: Give an example word and an example result.

Comment: `CASE WHEN .. OR .. OR.. THEN .. ELSE .. END`. Or use REGEX/RLIKE

Comment: Ok sorry, this was a poor post. Let me screenshot my results. Dont think I can paste my picture so i uploaded to imgur: http://imgur.com/a/MiNDZ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case Syntax Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710316/case-syntax-errors)