# Case Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case-statement

Hello I am attempting to do this with mySQL. I tried using SELECT IF and CASE to alter titles. Every title description has "A " in front of the description; even if the second word starts with a consonant. So I'm trying to query the descriptions but edit the ones with a leading consonant to start with "An ".

```
CASE
    WHEN description LIKE ('A A%') THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
    WHEN description LIKE ('A E%') THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
    WHEN description LIKE ('A I%') THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
    WHEN description LIKE ('A O%') THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
    WHEN description LIKE ('A U%') THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
END;
```

So this particular code was just giving me Error Code: 1064 syntax.

```
SELECT IF(description NOT LIKE ('A A%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A E%'), null, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A I%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A O%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))),
    IF(description NOT LIKE ('A U%'), NULL, CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description)))
FROM film_text;
```

This particular block of code returns separate columns however I'm trying to query all of this into one column.

What my IF block returns:

[image]

Comment: Your initial `CASE` expression looks on the right track.  What is the output from that?

Comment: May I suggest you upvote all answers you find helpful, and accept the one you find most useful? I see you've asked a couple of questions, but never upvoted nor accepted an answer. This helps the community, and other users who may have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use parentheses around the terms in your `LIKE` expressions.  This is probably the cause of the syntax error you are seeing.  Instead, try using this `CASE` expression having just a single condition:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN UPPER(description) NOT LIKE 'A A%' AND
                 UPPER(description) NOT LIKE 'A E%' AND
                 UPPER(description) NOT LIKE 'A I%' AND
                 UPPER(description) NOT LIKE 'A O%' AND
                 UPPER(description) NOT LIKE 'A U%'
            THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))   -- replace A with An
            ELSE description      -- otherwise use original description
       END AS description
FROM yourTable
```

You could also use `REGEXP` here with the negative character class `[^aeiou]` to match titles *not* beginning with a vowel:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN description REGEXP '^A [^aeiou]'
            THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
            ELSE description
       END AS description
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thank you both for the responses! I will look at these!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really several questions.

To get data from multiple "columns" returned as a single column, you'd use separate queries and use `UNION`, between them.

But this isn't really your issue.

It might be better to do the check (the "if") in the `WHERE` clause, and the replacement only once in `SELECT`.

This is untested, but may get you closer to what you want:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description)) AS descrip
FROM film_text
WHERE description REGEXP '^A [aeiou]';
```

The [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) does the check you were trying to perform in your `CASE`, and limits the result set to those rows only.

To do the whole thing, and return all descriptions, you can combine the `REGEX` syntax with the `CASE` you initially tried.

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN description REGEXP '^A [aeiou]'
    THEN CONCAT('An ', TRIM(LEADING 'A ' FROM description))
    ELSE description
  END AS description
FROM film_text;
```

Comment: The edited addition should address grabbing all. Case sensitivity depends first on table collation (not provided). Also, [from the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) "REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings."

Comment: Thank you very much for this breakdown. I am very new to SQL and this is helping make sense of things